# Why is my asp.net causing a runtime error?

Tags: asp.net, sql, string, connection, ado

I am trying to connect to a database on my local server. The database is called "dbtest." Of course, I have left off my actual password and replaced it with "password."

This is the typical code I see on every tutorial, but it doesn't work at all. Please help.

```
<%
    Dim con, rs 
    con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'I think it is something to do with this line
    con.Open "Provider=sqloledb;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dbtest;UID=administrator; PWD=password;"
    rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
%>
```

Comment: You should include the error message in your question.

Comment: As a software developer, what would you say if your users said the code you wrote "doesn't work at all?" Please provide, at the very least, the error message. It's nearly impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: Just says: Server Error in '/' Application.

This is windows server 2008, running on my LAN.

Comment: Here is the link to what I am talking about. Its my home pc so its just an ip address:

http://76.203.163.36/liams%20site/index.aspx

Comment: Shouldn't that be `con.Open("connection string here")`?

Comment: I have tried with and without parentheses. No difference

Comment: @George Marian: VBScript, which is what the above code is, doesn't require the parentheses if you aren't using the return value of a function.

Comment: @OneSHOT Thanks for the reminder.  I knew it was VB, as I've used it in the past.  Obviously, I forgot about this "feature.'

Answer (score 1):

This is not asp.net. This is classic ASP

You have to read about creating a database driven webapp first. 
Read about SqlDataSource and GridView controls. You won't need any code.

here: http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/querying-data-with-the-sqldatasource-control-cs

Answer (score 1):

The tutorials you are following may be a little out of date, .net includes updated classes for SQL data access, have a look here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx

Particularly at the SqlConnection class and SqlCommand class.

There is a useful tutorial that can be found [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx).

The equivalent of the ADODB.Recordset would be the SqlDataReader class.